# Resize img proportionally with CSS (caveat: preset max-width/height)

Tags: html, css, image, image-resizing, aspect-ratio

I have an overlarge image file, so I set desired max-width/height in pixels.
Now I want that image to shrink with page resize, while maintaining aspect ratio.
(In Chrome browser specifically, if that's relevant.)

```
<img style="max-width: 700px" src="http://static.photocdn.pt/images/articles/2017/04/28/iStock-516651882.jpg">
```

I cannot for the life of me get this to work. I tried setting max-height.

```
img {
max-height: 100vh;
}
```

But while it resizes vertically very nicely, it doesn't resize horizontally. As in if the screen is too narrow, it overflows to the right.

---

UPDATE:

Okay, so best I've come up with is:

```
<img style="width: 700px" src="http://static.photocdn.pt/images/articles/2017/04/28/iStock-516651882.jpg">
```

and CSS:

```
img {
max-height: 100vh;
max-width 100%;
object-fit:scale-down;
}
```

It works, it scales both ways ... it sometimes leaves a huge white-space between the image and the side borders when the image is scaled down. But I suppose that's better than a big whitespace gap above/below when you set img height instead. At least now it's not displacing my text (which is above/below, not around the image).

Only real solution seems to be to go without borders. Not great aesthetically, but I may have to consider it 'good enough' unless someone has a better answer?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Show us some code. Did you try with object-fit or background-size?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm new. Not sure what you mean by MCVE?

Background-size doesn't seem relevent. Not a background image.

Will check object-fit.

Comment: Okay, object-fit seems to give the same issue as above: resizes if screen is too short, but not if too narrow.

Comment: Did you try on the link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: I did check that link. Also, spoke too soon about object-fit. Sort of. Managed to get working with specified 'max-height' as 'height' instead, 'max-height: 100vh', 'max-width 100%', and 'object-fit:scale-down'. Problem is there is a big white-space between image and left/right borders.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for a generic case. It will not go over the max, but will resize smaller appropriately.

```
<div style="max-width: 700px">
 <img style="height: auto; width: 100%"  
  src="http://static.photocdn.pt/images/articles/2017/04/28/iStock-516651882.jpg">
</div>
```

I made some changes using your image, I think this is resizing like you described.

Comment: That doesn't resize at all for me. (I'll try and add some code in a tick if that helps.)

Comment: I am not at a spot I can test. may need `display: block`?

Comment: Nope, still no change.

Comment: It does resize both ways ... but doesn't maintain aspect ratio.

Comment: I removed the `max-height` from the parent and set the hight on the child to `auto`.

Comment: Maintains aspect ratio, but only resizes with screen width, not screen height.